# Does every set have a derangement?

Tags: set-theory, derangements

A derangement of a set $A$ is a bijection from $A$ to itself with no fixed points. Is it the case that every infinite set has a derangement?

Comment: If the set is finite, any cycle is a derangement. Approximately $1/e$ of all permutations is a derangement.

Comment: And if $A$ is infinite, I suspect this is equivalent to the set having a well ordering, which is equivalent to the axiom of choice.

Comment: If the set is countable, fix an enumeration of it and swap pairs of adjacent elements, as in $2n-1\leftrightarrow 2n$.

Comment: ^ right ... also equivalent to Zorn's Lemma.

Comment: Sets of cardinality $1$ have no derangements.  All other finite sets, including the empty set, have at least one derangement.

Comment: @lfh: Cycles of length $1$ are not derangements.

Answer (score 2):

If $A$ is infinite, then it is in bijection with $\lbrace 0,1\rbrace\times A$. Swapping $0$ with $1$ is a derangement of $\lbrace 0,1\rbrace\times A$, and hence, using the mentioned bijection, a derangement of $A$.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all the elements are different, the bijections of a set of size $n$ are equivalent to permutations: label the elements $1,2,\ldots,n$. So there are as many derangements for a set of size $n$ as there are for the numbers $1,2\ldots,n$

Comment: Obviously it's true for the finite case. I'm mainly asking about the infinite case.

Comment: @Nishant then you should make that clear in the title of your question!

Comment: But I said "every set," and there exist infinite sets.